# Ansicon doesn't install from python but only from cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, ansicon

I'm trying to install ansicon on Windows 8.1. I extracted the files and got to the level that I need to call `ansicon -i`. When I type this in my cmd and run python scripts that works great but when I call t from python by `os.system('ansicon -i')` that doesn't work and seems like it doesn't have any influence on the cmd.

Why `os.system('ansicon -i')` doesn't work and what alternative method can I use from within python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it’s not the `-i` flag that really does the work. `-i` only tells it to add itself to AutoRun. The `-p` flag that `-i` implies is what really does the work: `-p` tells it to inject a DLL into the parent process, and therein lies the problem: when you use `os.system`, you spawn a shell, which then runs the command you give it. But then you have Python running `cmd` running `ansicon`, and `ansicon` will inject into `cmd`, and then `cmd`, having finished its work, will exit.

Rather than using `os.system`, use the `subprocess` module, e.g.:

```
subprocess.check_call(['ansicon', '-p'])
```

The `subprocess` module (unlike `os.system`) will execute the command directly without a shell in-between (unless you pass `shell=True`). Then Python will spawn `ansicon`, and `ansicon` will inject into Python, as desired.

That said, rather than having `ansicon` inject itself into Python, Python could probably just load the DLL itself, avoiding some hardship:

```
import sys
import math
import ctypes

bitness = 1 << round(math.log2(round(math.log2(sys.maxsize + 1))))
ctypes.WinDLL('ANSI{}.DLL'.format(bitness))
```